# bitbake: how to resume compilation

Tags: qt5, yocto, bitbake

During a `bitbake <image>` execution, 3 errors are generated and the building process stopped.
Here the last lines of the output:

```
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/temp/log.do_compile.26600)
ERROR: Task (/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtwebkit_git.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 7532 tasks of which 6688 didn't need to be rerun and 2 failed.
NOTE: Writing buildhistory

Summary: 2 tasks failed:
  /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qt3d_git.bb:do_compile
  /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtwebkit_git.bb:do_compile
Summary: There were 2 WARNING messages shown.
Summary: There were 3 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

The `-k` argument is defined as follow:

```
-k, --continue        Continue as much as possible after an error. While the
                        target that failed and anything depending on it cannot
                        be built, as much as possible will be built before
                        stopping.
```

So it doesn't retry the failed tasks. And, actually, does nothing.
Here the last 50 lines of the log file of the last error:

```
$ tail -n 50 /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/temp/log.do_compile.26600
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WTF/wtf/text/WTFString.h:769,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WebCore/platform/ValueToString.h:35,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WebCore/platform/LayoutUnit.h:34,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WebCore/rendering/AutoTableLayout.h:24,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WebCore/rendering/AutoTableLayout.cpp:23,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WebCore/rendering/RenderingAllInOne.cpp:28:
/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WTF/wtf/HashTraits.h:226:8: note: 'struct WTF::KeyValuePair<std::pair<JSC::JSObject*, std::pair<unsigned int, const JSC::ClassInfo*> >, JSC::Weak<JSC::Structure> >' declared here
 struct KeyValuePair {
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WTF/wtf/HashMap.h:25,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WebCore/platform/ThreadGlobalData.h:30,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WebCore/dom/EventNames.h:25,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WebCore/dom/EventTarget.h:35,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WebCore/dom/Node.h:28,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WebCore/dom/ContainerNode.h:29,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WebCore/page/FrameView.h:30,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WebCore/rendering/RenderBox.h:26,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WebCore/rendering/RenderBlock.h:28,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WebCore/rendering/RenderTable.h:30,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WebCore/rendering/AutoTableLayout.cpp:25,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WebCore/rendering/RenderingAllInOne.cpp:28:
/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WTF/wtf/HashTable.h: In instantiation of 'static void WTF::HashTableBucketInitializer<true>::initialize(Value&) [with Traits = WTF::HashMap<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject>, WTF::PtrHash<void*>, WTF::HashTraits<void*>, WTF::HashTraits<JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> > >::KeyValuePairTraits; Value = WTF::KeyValuePair<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> >]':
/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WTF/wtf/HashTable.h:855:90:   required from 'static void WTF::HashTable<Key, Value, Extractor, HashFunctions, Traits, KeyTraits>::initializeBucket(WTF::HashTable<Key, Value, Extractor, HashFunctions, Traits, KeyTraits>::ValueType&) [with Key = void*; Value = WTF::KeyValuePair<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> >; Extractor = WTF::KeyValuePairKeyExtractor<WTF::KeyValuePair<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> > >; HashFunctions = WTF::PtrHash<void*>; Traits = WTF::HashMap<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject>, WTF::PtrHash<void*>, WTF::HashTraits<void*>, WTF::HashTraits<JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> > >::KeyValuePairTraits; KeyTraits = WTF::HashTraits<void*>; WTF::HashTable<Key, Value, Extractor, HashFunctions, Traits, KeyTraits>::ValueType = WTF::KeyValuePair<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> >]'
/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WTF/wtf/HashTable.h:1146:29:   required from 'static WTF::HashTable<Key, Value, Extractor, HashFunctions, Traits, KeyTraits>::ValueType* WTF::HashTable<Key, Value, Extractor, HashFunctions, Traits, KeyTraits>::allocateTable(unsigned int) [with Key = void*; Value = WTF::KeyValuePair<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> >; Extractor = WTF::KeyValuePairKeyExtractor<WTF::KeyValuePair<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> > >; HashFunctions = WTF::PtrHash<void*>; Traits = WTF::HashMap<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject>, WTF::PtrHash<void*>, WTF::HashTraits<void*>, WTF::HashTraits<JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> > >::KeyValuePairTraits; KeyTraits = WTF::HashTraits<void*>; WTF::HashTable<Key, Value, Extractor, HashFunctions, Traits, KeyTraits>::ValueType = WTF::KeyValuePair<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> >]'
/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WTF/wtf/HashTable.h:1194:32:   required from 'WTF::HashTable<Key, Value, Extractor, HashFunctions, Traits, KeyTraits>::ValueType* WTF::HashTable<Key, Value, Extractor, HashFunctions, Traits, KeyTraits>::rehash(unsigned int, WTF::HashTable<Key, Value, Extractor, HashFunctions, Traits, KeyTraits>::ValueType*) [with Key = void*; Value = WTF::KeyValuePair<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> >; Extractor = WTF::KeyValuePairKeyExtractor<WTF::KeyValuePair<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> > >; HashFunctions = WTF::PtrHash<void*>; Traits = WTF::HashMap<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject>, WTF::PtrHash<void*>, WTF::HashTraits<void*>, WTF::HashTraits<JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> > >::KeyValuePairTraits; KeyTraits = WTF::HashTraits<void*>; WTF::HashTable<Key, Value, Extractor, HashFunctions, Traits, KeyTraits>::ValueType = WTF::KeyValuePair<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> >]'
/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WTF/wtf/HashTable.h:453:25:   required from 'void WTF::HashTable<Key, Value, Extractor, HashFunctions, Traits, KeyTraits>::shrink() [with Key = void*; Value = WTF::KeyValuePair<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> >; Extractor = WTF::KeyValuePairKeyExtractor<WTF::KeyValuePair<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> > >; HashFunctions = WTF::PtrHash<void*>; Traits = WTF::HashMap<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject>, WTF::PtrHash<void*>, WTF::HashTraits<void*>, WTF::HashTraits<JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> > >::KeyValuePairTraits; KeyTraits = WTF::HashTraits<void*>]'
/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WTF/wtf/HashTable.h:1132:13:   required from 'void WTF::HashTable<Key, Value, Extractor, HashFunctions, Traits, KeyTraits>::removeIf(const Functor&) [with Functor = JSC::WeakGCMap<KeyArg, ValueArg, HashArg, KeyTraitsArg>::pruneStaleEntries() [with KeyArg = void*; ValueArg = JSC::JSObject; HashArg = WTF::PtrHash<void*>; KeyTraitsArg = WTF::HashTraits<void*>]::<lambda(WTF::HashMap<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject>, WTF::PtrHash<void*>, WTF::HashTraits<void*>, WTF::HashTraits<JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> > >::KeyValuePairType&)>; Key = void*; Value = WTF::KeyValuePair<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> >; Extractor = WTF::KeyValuePairKeyExtractor<WTF::KeyValuePair<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> > >; HashFunctions = WTF::PtrHash<void*>; Traits = WTF::HashMap<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject>, WTF::PtrHash<void*>, WTF::HashTraits<void*>, WTF::HashTraits<JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> > >::KeyValuePairTraits; KeyTraits = WTF::HashTraits<void*>]'
/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WTF/wtf/HashMap.h:421:5:   required from 'void WTF::HashMap<KeyArg, MappedArg, HashArg, KeyTraitsArg, MappedTraitsArg>::removeIf(const Functor&) [with Functor = JSC::WeakGCMap<KeyArg, ValueArg, HashArg, KeyTraitsArg>::pruneStaleEntries() [with KeyArg = void*; ValueArg = JSC::JSObject; HashArg = WTF::PtrHash<void*>; KeyTraitsArg = WTF::HashTraits<void*>]::<lambda(WTF::HashMap<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject>, WTF::PtrHash<void*>, WTF::HashTraits<void*>, WTF::HashTraits<JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> > >::KeyValuePairType&)>; KeyArg = void*; MappedArg = JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject>; HashArg = WTF::PtrHash<void*>; KeyTraitsArg = WTF::HashTraits<void*>; MappedTraitsArg = WTF::HashTraits<JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> >]'
/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/JavaScriptCore/runtime/WeakGCMapInlines.h:52:5:   required from 'void JSC::WeakGCMap<KeyArg, ValueArg, HashArg, KeyTraitsArg>::pruneStaleEntries() [with KeyArg = void*; ValueArg = JSC::JSObject; HashArg = WTF::PtrHash<void*>; KeyTraitsArg = WTF::HashTraits<void*>]'
/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/JavaScriptCore/runtime/WeakGCMapInlines.h:39:9:   required from 'JSC::WeakGCMap<KeyArg, ValueArg, HashArg, KeyTraitsArg>::WeakGCMap(JSC::VM&) [with KeyArg = void*; ValueArg = JSC::JSObject; HashArg = WTF::PtrHash<void*>; KeyTraitsArg = WTF::HashTraits<void*>]'
/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/JavaScriptCore/API/JSWeakObjectMapRefInternal.h:60:30:   required from here
/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WTF/wtf/HashTable.h:848:19: warning: 'void* memset(void*, int, size_t)' clearing an object of type 'struct WTF::KeyValuePair<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> >' with no trivial copy-assignment; use value-initialization instead [-Wclass-memaccess]
             memset(&bucket, 0, sizeof(bucket));
             ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WTF/wtf/text/CString.h:30,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WTF/wtf/text/StringView.h:33,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WTF/wtf/text/StringConcatenate.h:36,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WTF/wtf/text/AtomicString.h:378,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WTF/wtf/text/WTFString.h:769,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WebCore/platform/ValueToString.h:35,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WebCore/platform/LayoutUnit.h:34,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WebCore/rendering/AutoTableLayout.h:24,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WebCore/rendering/AutoTableLayout.cpp:23,
                 from /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WebCore/rendering/RenderingAllInOne.cpp:28:
/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WTF/wtf/HashTraits.h:226:8: note: 'struct WTF::KeyValuePair<void*, JSC::Weak<JSC::JSObject> >' declared here
 struct KeyValuePair {
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/temp/log.do_compile.26600)
```

As far as I understand the error is:

> 'struct WTF::KeyValuePair >' declared here

But because it's not my code I don't understand how one should handle such a situation.
I don't think the error is actually in the code, perhaps there was some out-of-sync operations or it ran out of memory? What is the right approach to resume the compilation? Just `bitbake <image>` again?

### UPDATE

In the log file there's only one match for `error`:

```
$ cat /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/temp/log.do_compile.26600 | grep error

arm-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi-g++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
```

And here the previous lines:

```
$ sed -n 132700,132717p /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/temp/log.do_compile.26600 

/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/qtwebkit/5.11.2+gitAUTOINC+beaeeb9988-r0/git/Source/WTF/wtf/HashTraits.h:226:8: note: 'struct WTF::KeyValuePair<std::pair<JSC::JSObject*, std::pair<unsigned int, const JSC::ClassInfo*> >, JSC::Weak<JSC::Structure> >' declared here
 struct KeyValuePair {
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:636266: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
{standard input}:636484: Error: found '
', expected: ')'
{standard input}: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing .cfi_endproc directive
{standard input}:636484: Error: can't resolve `.LC553' {*UND* section} - `.LPIC744' {*UND* section}
arm-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi-g++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: There might be many possible reasons why a package compilation has failed: compiler version, wrong dependencies, etc. Is this a native version of qtwebkit you're trying to build?

Comment: btw, check the log fail you see on the bottom and look for `error:` - most likely, the actual error is different.

Comment: I didn't change nothing. It's the default build for STM32MP1 `DISTRO=openstlinux-eglfs`, `IMAGE=st-image-example-qt`. I've updated the question with the error lines in the log file.

Comment: I see you're using qt 5.11. is it bumping it to 5.13 is an option for you? also, I would post the full log on pastebin - that might be helpful.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk, the full log is over 74 MB. Upgrading to 5.13 will be nice, indeed. But actually my question was about how to handle such a scenario in general. In the specific case I'm not interested in qtwebkit and I'm looking how to disable it...

Comment: try adding `DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "webengine"` to your `conf/local.conf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to have a recipe be rebuilt because you think it may have failed due to lack of memory, disk, etc it can be helpful to `bitbake -c clean RECIPE` as while bitbake will retry to build, the particular build system used by RECIPE might not recover gracefully.

Comment: So, if `bitbake -c clean RECIPE` exits successfully (i.e. the errors were due a temporary conditions) after that should I `bitbake IMAGE` again to complete the building?

Comment: Assuming that the problem was a lack of memory or similar and not that there's a problem with the build configuration, etc, itself, yes.